# How to show progress bar in percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, progress-bar

How I can show the progress of my upload on the screen in percents? I would like to show the bar that starts with 0% and output percentage from `percentComplete` variable. Once upload is completed I would like to see message completed in the progress bar. If anyone can provide some examples I would appreciate that. Thank you.

```
<div>Select file for upload:   
    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" onChange="fileUpload()"/>
    <span id="showBar"></span>
</div>
```

Here is my JQuery function:

```
function fileUpload(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var file = fileExist.files[0];

    reader.onload = function(e) {
        var text = reader.result.split(/\r\n|\n/);
        var myForm = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'));                       

        $.ajax({
            /*Start-Progress Bar Code*/
            xhr: function(){
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
                    if(evt.lengthComputable){
                        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
                        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
                        console.log(percentComplete);

                        if(percentComplete === 100){
                            console.log("Successfully uploaded!");
                        }
                    }
                },false);
                return xhr;
                },
                /*End*/
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'FileUpload.cfc?method=uploadFile',
                data: new FormData($('#myForm')[0]),
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                processData: false,
                dataType: 'json'
            }).done(function(obj){
                if(obj.STATUS === 200){
                    $('#myForm')[0].reset();
                }else{
                    alert('Error!');
                }
            }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert(errorThrown);
            })
    }
    reader.readAsText(file, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Comment: Why do you read a file and don't use it for anything?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered plupload? This is their core example, with simple textual percentage: http://www.plupload.com/examples/core

Comment: I prefer my JavaScript/JQuery method for upload, code works fine I just need the part that will show the progress on the screen. Like percentage bar starting from 0% all the way up to 100% then to hide once is done.